# Does a New Zealander need a transit visa if in Australia for over 8 hours transit on the return trip back to NZ?

Tags: transit-visas, australia, new-zealand-citizens

I am a New Zealander traveling from NZ to Canada with a transit in Australia for 4 hours. I figure that will be ok. However on my return trip back to New Zealand I will have a transit in Australia for 8 hours 20 minutes before the flight back home to New Zealand. Am I required to get a transit visa for this amount of time in Australia? I have been on the Australian Border website but I am still unsure if what it says about the transit visa applies to NZ citizens if they are in transit NOT within the 8 hour time limit before boarding, as specified on the website - and as this will be the case on my way back through Australia I don't know if this over 8 hour time frame meets the criteria to not need one.  Any advice as to if it is necessary to get a transit visa would be good. Thank you if anyone can help.

Answer (score 18):

Nope, not at all.  You're a Kiwi, and we can waltz in without even speaking to a border guard, if you have a smart passport (chip in it).

Example: Yesterday I came back from Japan to Sydney. 20 min after landing I was walking to the train. All I had to do was swipe my passport and declare some medicines.

When I moved here, I actually asked if there was anything else I had to do to 'immigrate'.  Nope. Walk in, get a tax number and start working.

On other occasions enroute to NZ from say, London or Hong Kong, I've had the day in Sydney and gone into town to meet friends, before returning to the airport. No problems.

*footnote* - if you have a criminal record or have previously required a visa (some old laws require NZers arriving by sea to get a visa(!) then different rules may apply.

Comment: Fun fact: New Zealand is mentioned as an Australian state in the Australian constitution :)

Comment: @JonathanReez I thought it was just an 'offer' to the colony to join?

Comment: Actually you can come into Australia, live there, work there, claim medical benefits without any pre-conditions at all. Only thing is you can't get elected to Parliament :)

Comment: @Andrew Or govt support after a natural disaster

Comment: @Andrew or get the dole, or vote...

Comment: "The States shall mean such of the colonies of New South Wales, New
         Zealand, Queensland, Tasmania, Victoria, Western Australia, and
         South Australia, including the northern territory of South
         Australia, as for the time being are parts of the Commonwealth, and
         such colonies or territories as may be admitted into or established
         by the Commonwealth as States; and each of such parts of the
         Commonwealth shall be called a State." - it's mentioned on par with regular territories.

Answer (score 6):

No.  Under the [Trans-Tasman Travel Arrangement](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Life/New-) you will be issued a Special Category visa (subclass 444), which is valid for your entire length of stay in Australia, however long that is so long as you remain a New Zealand citizen, and so long as you meet the health and character considerations.